# How to select every possible combination of two ids from two different tables that don't share a join

Tags: sql, oracle

So I am trying to insert all possible combinations of IDs from two unrelated tables into a reference table that i created.  Below are my tables along with some sample data:

```
Table 1 (Entity):
Entity_ID    Entity_Create_dt
   1             04-APR-18
   2             04-APR-18
   3             04-APR-18

Table 2 (TimeZone):
Time_Zone_Id     Time_Zone_Create_Dt
   1               04-APR-18
   2               04-APR-18
```

Desired End Result:

```
Entity_ID     Time_Zone_Id
   1               1
   1               2
   2               1
   2               2
   3               1
   3               2
```

What I've tried (but failed):

```
select entity_id, time_zone_id
  from (select entity as entity_id
             , null as time_zone_id 
          from entity
        UNION ALL
        select null as entity_id
             , time_zone_id as time_zone_id
          from time_zone);
```

How do i get my desired result? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.entity_id, t.time_zone_id
FROM entity e
CROSS JOIN time_zone t
ORDER BY e.entity_id, t.time_zone_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Select DISTINCT e.entity_id, tz.time_zone_id
from entity e cross join time_zone tz
```